# Unable to determine Parameter value in parameterized Jenkins job with Web Sphere Deployement (EAR path)

Tags: jenkins, websphere, jenkins-plugins

**Jenkins ERROR:** No deployable artifacts found in path:

> D:\Apps\Jenkins\workspace\${TEMP}

The value of the Temp is assigned in the String Parameter.

But the value of the TEMP is not injected.
My web Sphere Deployement plugin version Is 1.3.4
How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the plugin to v1.5.6 and try again. I don't believe parameter expansion was in v1.3.4.

Comment: Even though I  changed plugin to v1.5.6 I am getting same problems. parameter is not expanding.

Comment: Just published v1.6.0 even though this will not address your issue... I believe the paths are relative to the jenkins workspace. I'm not sure if you can specify absolute paths, I could be wrong though.